# ¿Cómo ordenar un arreglo en la lectura o impresion del mismo del mismo?

Tags: java, array, ordenamiento

Me piden realizar un programa (Materia: Estructura de datos) con un arreglo, que al ingresar los datos este mismo se vaya ordenando sin recurrir a algún método externo. Si no, *en el propio de escritura al arreglo o impresión del arreglo*.

Esta es la estructura del programa:

```java
public void leer_vec (String vecu[],String vecd[], int N) throws IOException {
    for (i = 0; i <= N-1; i++) {
        System.out.println("Como se llama el jugador #"+(i+1)+" : ");
        vecu[i]=objLect.leer();
        System.out.println("Cual fue el puntaje del jugador #"+(i+1)+" : ");
        vecd[i]=objLect.leer();
    }
}

public void imprimir_vec(String vecu[],String vecd[], int N) {
    for (i = 0; i <= N-1; i++) {
        System.out.println("El jugador: "+vecu[i]+ ", tiene un Score de: "+vecd[i]);
    }
}
```

Así como se va introduciendo cada valor en el arreglo, que a la vez se vaya organizando de mayor a menor o que también en la impresión se organice.

Reiterando, que NO puedo usar otro método externo para organizar.

Comment: Que has intentado hasta el momento?

Comment: Pense en utilizar banderas (Booleanos) para marcar indices libres y de ahi mover los datos, asi mismo, mantener un For dinamico que vaya analizando los datos que ya esten dentro y comparar entre ellos

Comment: Primero deberías leer sobre algoritmos de ordenación (https://sites.google.com/a/espe.edu.ec/programacion-ii/home/a1-arreglos/algoritmos-de-ordenacion-y-busqueda) 
Luego para cada dato que agregues al arreglo deberas ejecutar el algoritmo que elijas sobre el arreglo

Comment: Ok bro, me lo leo